# How do I match a regex pattern multiple times?

Tags: regex, matlab

I have a log file which I am trying to scan for patterns and count the number of times certain patterns are seen. The log looks like this

---

11298 [out] [worker:83] data has been rebuilt.

11299 [out] [worker:83] END Building data for foo

11299 [out] [worker:83] END Building data for bar

11300 [out] [worker:83] BEGIN Building data for baz

11301 [err] [worker:83] Putin bombed Syria

---

I am interested in all the lines starting with [out] and containing END, BEGIN or rebuilt (need to count them separately). So I thought the following regex

`(out.*END)*`

would match the patch the pattern `out] anything here END` multiple times, but it only gives me the first instance of `out` in my file and stops. Can someone point me in the right direction ?

I am doing this in MATLAB with the syntax  `regexp(txt,expr,'start')`

Comment: I found the answer myself. The default behavior of `.` in MATLAB regex is different from the standard (it includes newline) and there is an option `'dotexceptnewline'` that can be used to switch to the standard behavior.

Comment: Spotted your comment after posting answer. Glad you found it.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a doc: http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/regexp.html

`regexp` by default returns all matches.

Try playing with options and outkeys (passed as 3rd argument). It looks like this one could help: `'dotexceptnewline'` - your regex is greedy and probably matches whole thing (from first `out` to last `END`).

Try using outkey `'match'` instead of `'start'`.

Also check if your results aren't truncated by mistake.